# Why are flat_set and flat_map not ContiguousRange?

Tags: c++, templates, c++20

Is it done on purpose(lack of `data()` member function)? It prevents decaying from `flat_set`/`flat_map` to `std::span` which can be useful if we treate `flat_set`/`flat_map` as sorted `vector`.

Is it safe to make sth like that?

```
template<typename T>
std::span<const T> make_span(const std::flat_set<T>& fset)
{
    return std::span<const T>{fset.empty() ? nullptr : std::addressof(*fset.begin()),
                              fset.size()};
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::flat_set` is supposed to be a container *adaptor* (like `std::queue` or `std::stack`), and shall specifically work with container backends that support random access iteration, like `std::vector` and `std::deque` do. From [P1222](https://wg21.link/p1222) (the `std::flat_set` proposal):

> Any sequence container supporting random access iteration can be used to instantiate `flat_set`. In partic-ular, `vector` and `deque` can be used.

No requirements are imposed w.r.t. any contiguous nature of the storage, and `std::deque` indeed doesn't have a `data()` function, nor does it store its elements in a contiguous range. This means:

1. Yes, it is done on purpose. As `std::flat_set` is supposed to be an adaptor, access to a possibly underlying contiguous range can be delegated to the backend, and the requirements for `std::flat_set` can be more flexible.
2. You `make_span` template should be safe as it only accepts `std::flat_set` instances with the default underlying container, `std::vector`. I think it's a bit dangerous though - when compilation fails for a `std::flat_set<T, std::deque<T>>`, someone might be tempted to add the second template parameter `std::flat_set<T, Container<T>>` and run into UB when accessing elements beyond the first underlying `std::deque` bucket.

Also note that `std::flat_map` in its [current form](https://wg21.link/p0429) uses two separate containers for key and value storage to improve cache locality while searching for a matching key. Even if `std::flat_map` required a contiguous backend, this can't go along with a meaningful `std::flat_map::data()` access function.

Comment: ad 2. shouldn't passing `std::flat_set<int, std::deque<int>>` fail when passed to function expecting `std::flat_set<int>`(which has default `std::vector`)?